# Php Storm with "Strip trailing spaces on Save" set to "All" ignores line with cursor

Tags: phpstorm, removing-whitespace

Having 2 lines with trailing spaces and cursor at the end of the 2nd one, on save action only trailing spaces from 1st line will be striped.

I mean, if I have this:

```
1st_line[space]
2nd_line[space][cursor]
```

after save action I will have

```
1st_line
2nd_line[space][cursor]
```

Is it possible to also strip the line with cursor?

(It can be a philosophical question - Is space in the 2nd line really trailing or not? Though there is cursor behind it)

Comment: *"Is it possible? to strip also line with cursor?"* -- No, it's intentional (requested by users), otherwise it will also remove indentation when cursor is on new empty line and you plan to continue typing after save operation is done.

Comment: Why not customize this? I have a habit to save after finishing some part, not before starting next. This is not huge problem, but introduces possibility to make a mistake.

Comment: The Issue Tracker where you can leave your suggestions in form of **concrete** ideas is located here: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI . P.S. I personally do not think that such option will be introduced.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [vote](http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23368682) of this feature request:

- [Strip white space left of caret on manual save](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-114099)

Answer (score 5):

> Disable (uncheck) the option "Always keep trailing spaces on caret line" under `Settings`|`Editor`|`General`|`Other`|`Strip trailing spaces on Save`.

Taken from [the issue-link](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-114099) @CrazyCoder provided in his answer. It is included since PHP Storm version `2016.3.2`.